# How to create a LineChart with dynamic width with react-chartjs?

Tags: javascript, charts, reactjs

I am trying create a LineChart with dynamic width but only get the first value.

```
<LineChart data = {this.state.dataLine} options = {{}} width={this.state.widthChart} height = "250" />
```

Comment: Have you tried setting an inline style? https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

Comment: width is a prop of the component LineChart, the problem is the re-render when change state.... the newest LineChart have a prop redraw that trigger method destroy and re-render the chart...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how one would achieve this in react-chartjs, but it's pretty easy in react-vis, which is similar.

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  FlexibleWidthXYPlot,
  HorizontalGridLines,
  LineSeries
} from 'react-vis';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FlexibleWidthXYPlot
        height={300}>
        <HorizontalGridLines />
        <YAxis />
        <XAxis />
        <LineSeries data={myData}/>
      </FlexibleWidthXYPlot>
    );
  }
}
```

For more check here http://uber.github.io/react-vis/#/documentation/api-reference/flexible-plots